# Como mandar un parámetro temporal?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

me gustaria como puedo mandar un campo que estoy llenando desde mi model con un enum, pero ese campo no existe en mi tabla, solo lo requiero para poder hacer una validación y redireccionar al usuario a vistas especificas, sin que me mande el error de `Invalid column`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi modelo enum en Usuario

```
public enum UsuarioMarca
{
    Champion,
    Chicos,
    Aeropostale,
    CharlesAndKeith
}
```

El cual lo mando a llamar a la vista de esta manera:

```
<div class="col-md-6 mb-2">
            <label for="country" class="form-label">Marca</label>
            @Html.DropDownList("Marca", new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(UsuarioMarca))), "Selecciona una opción", new { @class = "form-select" })
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Please select a valid country.
            </div>
</div>
```

Este es mi controlador donde se realiza mi validación de mi usuario para poder mandarlo a una visa:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Login(Usuario usuario)
    {
        string contraMayus = usuario.Contrasena.ToUpper();
        contraMayus = ConvertirContra(contraMayus);

        Usuario usuarioLog = usuarioORM.Usuarios.Where(x => 
            x.Usuario1 == usuario.Usuario1 && x.Contrasena == contraMayus).FirstOrDefault();

        if (usuarioLog == null)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Hubó algun error, revisa tus accesos!";
            return View();
        }

        //Guardar información en una sesión
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("Usuario", usuarioLog.Usuario1);
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("Inforperfil", usuarioLog.Inforperfil);

        Response.Cookies.Append("UltimaConexion", DateTime.Now.ToString());

        return RedirectToAction("Dashboard");
    }
```

Alguna sugerencia de como poder solo almacenarlo sin que lo compare con las tablas que estan en mi base de datos, ya que no existe y no puedo hacer modificaciones a la BD.

Comment: ¿Que ORM estas utilizando? Veo que tienes "usuarioORM" pero no se que tipo es ? o que framework estas utilizando? Porque asi te podemos ayudar en este tema de "no interferir dicha columna" en las querys de la DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digamos que tienes una clase Usuario, debes agregar el atributo NotMapped esto evitará enviarlo a la base de datos.

```
public class Usuario
{
  //otras propiedades

  [NotMapped]
  public UsuarioMarca Marca {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Yussef, funciono muy bien.